# How to shuffle multiple div elements contained in td and another div

Tags: javascript, html

I have 16 divs:
**HTML**

```
  <table id="table1">
  <tr id="tr1">
    <td id="divdrag" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <div id="div_content1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><p id="p1">5</p></div></td>
    <td id="divdrag" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <div id="div_content2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><p id="p1">11</p></div></td>
    <td id="divdrag" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <div id="div_content3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><p id="p1">1</p></div></td>
    <td id="divdrag" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <div id="div_content4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><p id="p1">4</p></div></td>
  </tr>

  ...
  ...
  ...

  <tr id="tr4">
    <td id="divdrag" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <div id="div_content13" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><p id="p1">12</p></div></td>
    <td id="divdrag" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <div id="div_content14" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><p id="p1">3</p></div></td>
    <td id="divdrag" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <div id="div_content15" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><p id="p1">9</p></div></td>
    <td id="divdrop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

I tried to shuffle them with this function (when page refreshes)
**JS**

```
onload = function(){
    var parent = document.getElementById('divdrag');
    var child = parent.children[1];
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    while (child.length) {
        frag.appendChild(child[Math.floor(Math.random() * child.length)]);
    }
    child.appendChild(frag);
}
```

Where I am mistaken?
Take a look of jsfiddle, because I am not allowed to post so much code: http://jsfiddle.net/2tESd/1/
Thank you!

Comment: Where's your allowDrop() and drop() declaration? Your code seems to be incomplete.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't be needful. However, I updated the fiddle :)

Comment: Note that for the code in your fiddle to work at all you need to change the second drop-down under Framework & Extensions from "onload" to one of the "No wrap" options: http://jsfiddle.net/2tESd/3/

Comment: Thanks for the advices, but somehow the divs don't shuffle when I press 'Run' (even with the ClassName changes thou)

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all, there could be one id with the same name, so you

```
document.getElementById('divdrag');
```

and you need to change them to classes

Comment: `document.getElementById()` doesn't return `null` when there are multiple elements of the specified id. Though of course having repeated ids is invalid.

Comment: I changed those ids to classes and edited but still nothing :/ Maybe there is something wrong with the shuffling algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following code in script tags.

```
 function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev)
{
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
onload = function(){
var parent = document.getElementById('divdrag');
var child = parent.children[1];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
while (child.length) {
    frag.appendChild(child[Math.floor(Math.random() * child.length)]);
}
child.appendChild(frag);
}
```

hope it works..

Comment: @getty - What about your answer is different to the OP's code?